# 18.04 boot problem uefi db

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a dual boot system (actually triple). Been working with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a MBR SSD and Windows also on an SSD drive. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an nvme drive (UEFI) and it seemed to work after converting windows to UEFI.

System is a new i7-8700K system 16 GB ram, with nvidia 1060 gpu

I couldn't boot into 18.04 but new how to fix this by trying to boot into repair mode and I did

```
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

now it boots but still complains about uefi db list that can not be found and missing keys.

below some perhaps relevant lines from dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-20-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-039) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-20.21-generic 4.15.17)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=dfe556c4-41cc-4e65-870c-0fed9ed93867 ro quiet splash
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset    [2]:  576, xstate_sizes    [2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset    [3]:  832, xstate_sizes    [3]:   64
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset    [4]:  896, xstate_sizes    [4]:   64
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] 
usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007a102fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000007a103000-0x000000007a103fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000007a104000-0x000000007a104fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000007a105000-0x000000008e28afff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008e28b000-0x000000008e746fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008e747000-0x000000008e7edfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008e7ee000-0x000000008eb9afff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008eb9b000-0x000000008f749fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008f74a000-0x000000008f7fefff] type 20
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008f7ff000-0x000000008f7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x000000008f800000-0x000000008fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820:     [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000046effffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.60 by American Megatrends
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x8e7ee000  ACPI=0x8e7ee000  SMBIOS=0x8f66c000  MPS=0xfcb30  ESRT=0x8bc3fe98  MEMATTR=0x88421018 
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0)
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.0 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7B46/Z370 KRAIT GAMING (MS-7B46), BIOS 1.00 08/29/2017
[    0.000000] e820: update     [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove     [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x46f000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: write-back
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 base 00C0000000 mask 7FC0000000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   1 base 00A0000000 mask 7FE0000000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   2 base 0090000000 mask 7FF0000000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   3 disabled
[    0.000000]   4 disabled
[    0.000000]   5 disabled
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000]   8 disabled
[    0.000000]   9 disabled
[    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration     [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x8f800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at     [mem 0x000fce20-0x000fce2f] mapped at     [    (ptrval)]
[    0.000000] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000008bc3fe98 to 0x000000008bc3fed0.
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at     [    (ptrval)] 95000 size 24576
...
...
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=dfe556c4-41cc-4e65-870c-0fed9ed93867 ro quiet splash
[    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
[    0.000000] Memory: 16266776K/16730936K available (12300K kernel code, 2470K rwdata, 4240K rodata, 2404K init, 2416K bss, 464160K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=12, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 39065 entries in 153 pages
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
...
...
[    4.881363] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    4.904364] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[    4.996564] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    4.996566] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    4.996567] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#9 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    4.996568] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 01 e2 00 00 02 00
[    4.996569] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1312648
[    5.024534] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.024535] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#10 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    5.024536] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#10 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    5.024537] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 01 e2 00 00 01 00
[    5.024538] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1312648
[    5.024552] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 328162, async page read
[    5.052528] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.052530] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#12 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    5.052531] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#12 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    5.052532] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 01 e3 00 00 01 00
[    5.052532] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1312652
[    5.052547] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 328163, async page read
[    5.080548] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.080549] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#13 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    5.080550] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#13 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    5.080551] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[    5.080552] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[    5.108549] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.108550] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    5.108552] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#14 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    5.108553] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[    5.108553] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[    5.108566] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[    5.136538] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.136540] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[    5.136541] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#16 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    5.136542] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[    5.136542] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
...
...
[    5.248543] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
[    5.248556] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1, async page read
[    5.276543] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[    5.304531] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1, async page read
[    7.776538] random: crng init done
[   10.004556] scsi_io_completion: 163 callbacks suppressed
[   10.004558] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   10.004559] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#20 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[   10.004560] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#20 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[   10.004561] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[   10.004562] print_req_error: 163 callbacks suppressed
[   10.004562] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
[   10.032534] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   10.032535] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#21 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[   10.032536] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#21 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[   10.032537] sr 2:0:0:0:     [sr0] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[   10.032538] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[   10.032539] buffer_io_error: 162 callbacks suppressed
...
...
[   11.886177] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   11.892947] Adding 16692220k swap on /dev/sdd5.  Priority:-3 extents:1 across:16692220k SSFS
[   11.917929] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   11.942088] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   12.134968] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
       on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
       requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
       drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
       corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
[   12.258125] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=1407 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258328] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=1411 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258379] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=1404 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258779] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1408 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258781] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1408 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258819] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=1405 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258821] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc//sanitized_helper" pid=1405 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258879] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4571/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1400 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258881] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4571/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1400 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.258906] audit: type=1400 audit(1526849677.670:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=1403 comm="apparmor_parser"
...
...
```

Please advice. Should I reinstall or is there a fix?. Tried boot-repair but that only made things worse.

Thanks, Robert